# Can anyone please explain the use of JdbcClientDetailsServiceBuilder?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am new to Spring Security, can anyone please explain the use of JdbcClientDetailsServiceBuilder?

I have to check whether the client id passed in the request is available in the client table, If yes then I have to dynamically pass the CLIENT_ID in the following code

```
 configurer.jdbc(dataSource).withClient(CLIENT_ID).secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
            .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE).accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).and().build();
```

Comment: Exactly, what are you asking for? I think spring documentation should answer this kind of questions.

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori what I have to do is I need to check the client ID passed in the postman request to fetch the access token should be available in the clients table in the database if the id is not present it should not grant the access token however in the code above the client id is passed in a static manner and always one client id is valid for the access token grant